# AngularJS $scope Undefined When Compiling Controller In Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using ant to build/uglyfy my AngularJS and each time I have a controller in a directive, I get an undefined $scope error. Example of code is this:

```
app.directive('directive1',['$compile', '$http',function($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller : function($scope) {
            var posts = {};
            this.addPosts = function($scope, newPosts) {

                angular.extend(posts, newPosts);
                //$scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.posts = posts;
                //});
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.posts = {};
        }
    };
}]);
```

My question is, how can I define the $scope of the controller to when it is compiled it doesn't come up as undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply the same minifier/ulgifier safe approach you did on the directive definition to your controller.

So your controller goes from:

```
controller : function($scope) {
```

to:

```
controller: ['$scope',function($scope) {
```

The uglifier is renaming `$scope` to something short like 'e' which is great for size but Angular doesn't know what to inject into 'e'.

The uglifier won't change a string.  So the new code, above, lets angular know it should inject $scope into 'e' (or whatever name the uglifier gives it).

Comment: You shouldn't need to, directive controllers have a set number of args. They are not freely injectable as a real controller is.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. This has changed... what I said used to be true but now angular actually does support injection and bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

`this.addPosts = function($scope, newPosts) {`

What is calling this function? Why are you trying to pass $scope into it? I think you should change it to:

`$scope.addPosts = function(newPosts) {`

Because you want to get the first $scope... not whatever scope you're attempting to pass into addPosts.

Comment: Not the problem or concern, the problem is the $scope does not persist when uglyfied. It works otherwise.

Comment: It might be your problem. A minifier will rewrite the first arg of controller as something like `function(a)` then the addPosts function will get minified as `function(b, c)`... I can't tell why you're writing your addPosts function like that. Can you explain why it's passing $scope into addPosts? That's just... odd.